# Roxy File Man Loading error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I am using [Roxy Fileman](http://www.roxyfileman.com/) in ckeditor to add and manage images. This was working perfectly in my local Xampp server. When i use it in live server, after click on browse, `E_LoadingAjax php/dirtree.php` error alert is shown.

[image]

can anyone know how to solve this?.

Comment: please check if hosts allows                                                     
     define('BASE_PATH', dirname (__FILE__)); 
on the file system.inc.php

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please do check that php-mbstring module is installed on your php. For me i just installed this module and now everything is working perfect.
For Ubuntu 16.4

Please type in terminal:

sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0

Then, restart apache2:

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: navigate to tiny\fileman\ and then open file system.inc.php and replace define('BASE_PATH', dirname (_FILE__)); with define('BASE_PATH', _DIR__);

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that the `.htaccess` file had a RewriteRule that was blocking http access to required files.

The [Roxy FAQ](http://www.roxyfileman.com/FAQ) says that you should be able to load `dirtree.php` in a browser window.  In my case, that file was throwing a 403 until I removed/updated the htaccess RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

for me this is useful.
in the php / functions.inc.php folder
there is a function

```
function listDirectory ($ path) {
   $ ret = @scandir ($ path);
   if ($ ret === false) {
     $ ret = array ();
     $ d = opendir ($ path);
     if ($ d) {
       while (($ f = readdir ($ d))! == false) {
         $ ret [] = $ f;
       }
       closedir ($ d);
     }
   }
```

change @scandir to scandir